# CanCan gem problems with create action having conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

sorry for my english... I am using cancan gem but I get a problem on new action when I do something like this...

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Post, :id => 1
  end
end
```

the new action controller has not an id, for that reason I am not authorized to create a new post :(

Some help?
Regards.

Comment: State the error you get when you try access the new action

Comment: CanCan::AccessDenied (You are not authorized to access this page.)

Comment: CanCan::AccessDenied (You are not authorized to access this page.) You need to give your PostController access to this action.

Comment: Are you using devise for authentication? and post model belongs to user right?

Answer (score 0):

> the new action ... has not an id ... I am not authorized to create a new post

Are you using `load_resource` in your controller?  `load_resource` will apply the *conditions* from your *ability definition*.  See [Authorizing controller actions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#new-and-create-actions).

Also, your ability definition is strange.  It's more common to say something like: users can manage their own posts and everyone can read.

```ruby
def initialize(user)
  can :read, Post
  can :manage, Post, :user_id => user.id
end
```